# How to estimate proper heading angle

Tags: mobile-robot, motion-planning, orientation

I obtain the heading or yaw angle from a source which I am not allowed to modify, but when the angle goes more than +180 or -180, it interchanges either from 180 to -180 or the other way around. Any suggestion on how to overcome this drastic angle changes will be appreciated.

Here is the plot of angle changes over time,

[image]

Update after @Chuc comment,
Here is what I feel like desired behaviour

[image]

Comment: +180 and -180 are both valid heading angles. What problem are you having? If it's a large delta between measured angles at subsequent timesteps, then you may want to add a conditional check to any calculation you're doing. E.g. 179 -> -179 is a difference of 2, not 358.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, GPrathap. It would help if you could explain how this is negatively affecting you and what you would like the alternative to be. If, for example, you want angles to be 0 to 360 instead of -180 to +180 then you'll still wind up with a jump when the angle wraps. If there's a particular (inverse) trig function that's giving you trouble we might be able to recommend an alternative, etc., but as it stands I think the best anyone can say is that you'll always wind up with a jump discontinuity.

Comment: @Chuck thank you for your reply, I send this yaw angle to control a quadcopter; when angle goes from -180 to 180 quadrotor just rotate. I want to avoid this. How actually approach this?

Comment: @GPrathap - *What is the problem* you are having with using a -180 to +180 reference? What is the alternative you would like to use? You could easily add 360 to any negative values, but then you have a 0-360 heading instead of a -180 to +180 heading; there's still a discontinuity. Are you using a reference that is also +/- 180? It's hard to give you meaningful help without knowing why **specifically** the +/- 180 feedback is giving you trouble.

Comment: @Chunk thank you again. I updated assuming that's what I feel like desired yaw angle

Comment: @GPrathap - You can't do that. Your hand-drawn picture shows a range of -pi to pi, and then you just draw an arrow to something that doesn't wrap, but there aren't any labels on it. As-drawn, do you mean you only want your headings to go from -2pi to 0? Do you want them from negative infinity to infinity? 0 to 2pi? It's still not clear what your desired output is.

Comment: @Chuck if I am able to get 0 to 2pi, would be enough as well. Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Based on your comment](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/21322/how-to-estimate-proper-heading-angle?noredirect=1#comment34968_21322):

> if I am able to get 0 to 2pi, would be enough as well.

The following code will do it:

```
modifiedHeading = SensorOutput();
if(modifiedHeading < 0)
{
    modifiedHeading += 360f;
}
```

But, as I've mentioned previously, you still have the jump discontinuity, but you've moved it from the 359/1 degree range from the 179/-179 degree range.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried this as well, seems to be I am trying something not possible :(

Comment: @GPrathap - I've said it many times now - *what are you trying to do?* You finally said 0 to 2pi works, and the code I gave above does *exactly* that. If there's something else you'd like to do then it might also be possible, but you need to be explicit with what you're wanting the output to be.

Comment: Sure, I will check properly and formulate as another question. Thanks for your help